# Is NGINX blocking flask backend code executing?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, flask-socketio

My flask web app is based on socket.io, flask, nginx and gunicorn. One of frontend features sends 1.3MB message to the backend using socket.io. I know that from 3.x socket.io maxHttpBufferSize was decreased from 100MB to 1MB so I have max_http_buffer_size limit set to 2MB on the server side. Everything works good, backend receiving message but after few seconds of executing code on backend side it stops without any information in nginx error.log and gunicorn.log. Web browser(Opera, Chrome) console does not return any error too. I think that the problem is on the nginx side because when I execute my app using only gunicorn it works in the right way.
Have you any idea what should I change in my nginx config? Or the problem is elsewhere?
I'm using

- **Python 3.7.9**,
- **python-engineio 4.0.0**,
- **python-socketio 5.0.2**,
- **Flask-SocketIO 5.0.0**,
- **Javascript SocketIO 3.0.0**
- **gunicorn 20.0.4**,
- **nginx 1.14.0**

My .service config file

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve <my_app>
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<my_user>
Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/app
Environment="PATH=/path/to/my/env/bin"

ExecStart=/path/to/my/env/bin/gunicorn --certfile=/path/to/my/app/cert.crt --keyfile=/path/to/my/app/key.key --access-logfile /path/to/my/app/gunicorn_logs.log --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --timeout 300 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 <my_app>:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My nginx proxy requests config

```
server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name <my_domain> <my_server_ip>;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server{
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;

        access_log /path/to/my/app/access.log;
        error_log /path/to/my/app/error.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/privkey.pem;

        server_name <my_domain> <my_server_ip>;

        proxy_read_timeout 300;

        # reverse proxy for HTTP connection
        location / {
                include proxy_params;

                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:5000/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        # reverse proxy for Socket.IO connections
        location /socket.io {
                proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:5000/socket.io;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }

        # let's encrypt host validation
        location ~ /.well-known{
                root /path/to/my/app/static/;        
        }
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Comment: What the loglevel of your nginx? If there is nothing in the "normal" error.log file try to run nignx in debug mode and send the request again. This will show a lot mor details.

Comment: @TimoStark, nginx debbuger returns two SSL errors, `SSL_read: 0; SSL_get_error: 5` and `SSL_read: -1; SSL_get_error: 2`